# Using praw, how can I iterate over all of a user's comments?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm just wondering if there's a simple enough way to iterate over all comments made by a particular user (I want to check for a particular phrase).
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 9):

You can't get all comments, if the user has more than 1,000 comments. It is a limitation of the reddit API. However, the code below will get (and print the body) of all comments made by a user.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit('Your unique user agent')
user = r.get_redditor('REDDITOR-USER-HANDLE')
for comment in user.get_comments(limit=None):
    print comment.body
```

A coupe notes:

- Remember to have a unique user agent
- `REDDITOR-USER-HANDLE` is the user name of the user you are looking at

Comment: For me to get my code working, I used .redditor and .comments.new instead of .get_redditor and .get_comments.